# Filter values in a column based on set rules

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
  Group    ID
   1      09239820
   2      2872498938
   2      1267
   3      23219823983
   3      267839236
   4      33287442
```

I want to replace the 1st, 2nd and 4th numbers in the ID column with letters

```
   Replace 1st with N
   Replace 2nd with X
   Replace 4TH with D
```

Expected output:

```
    Group    ID
     1      NX2D9820
     2      NX7D498938
     2      NX6D
     3      NX2D9823983
     3      NX7D39236
     4      NX2D7442
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.str.replace` with captured groups and back reference:

```
df.ID = df.ID.astype(str)

df.ID.str.replace('..(.).(.*)', r'NX\1D\2')

0        NX3D820
1     NX7D498938
2           NX6D
3    NX2D9823983
4      NX7D39236
5       NX2D7442
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex for that.

`^..(.).` matches the first 4 characters and captures the third one to replace it in the output using the backreference `\1`:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str).str.replace('^..(.).', r'NX\1D')
```

```
   Group           ID
0      1      NX3D820
1      2   NX7D498938
2      2         NX6D
3      3  NX2D9823983
4      3    NX7D39236
5      4     NX2D7442
```